# showing error message on after API call to Node express server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express, spotify

I am trying to handle errors on the front end based on a response received from my express server. I am making a POST request from the front end that sends data to the express server. This endpoint (called `/endpoint` below) then makes a request to the Spotify API and returns a list of songs. If this fails for some reason I want to let the user know on the front end. I thought the code I wrote below was correct, however it is not showing an error message when the Express request to Spotify fails.

Can anyone spot anything wrong with the code below?

Express App

```
app.post('/endpoint', function(req, res){
    var options = {
       url: url,
       method: 'POST',
       json: true
     }

    request-promise(options).then(function(body){
      console.log('All good!');
    }).catch(function(err) {
       if(err) {
         console.log(err);  
         res.json(err);     
       }
    });
}
```

jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'http://localhost:3000/endpoint',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
     },
     error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
     }
 });
```

Comment: it gets logged to the terminal console, but not the browser's console

Comment: i think its due to `res.json`. i think I need to use `res.send(err)` instead. it looks like its working with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an error status to response. From express Response API [Express 4.x](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res)

```
res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' });
```

Comment: i think its due to `res.json`. i think I need to use `res.send(err)` instead

Comment: @phantom If you use `res.send(err)` your frontend JS will receive it in `success` callback but you need proceed it via `error` callback I think

Comment: ah ok, you may be right as I am handling the error in my `success` method

Comment: beautiful! that is the solution!